# Why is my css not supported on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser

Hello to all and to all,

I'm a Junior developer and its going to be almost two weeks long as I struggle on a topic. My code works very well for the desktop version and on all browsers (Chrome, EI, Firefox, Edge).
On the other hand when I want to view my page on mobile everything works well on safari but for se that is Firefox and chrome is the disaster.
I have the impression that there are classes of my CSS that are not supported. On the other hand when I put the style in inline mode in my page html everything works well, weird all its !!!

Hoping that a savior can help me find a solution. I put you below my html code and css.

Good day everyone.

```css
body{
  background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0px;

}
.verso{

  width: 370px;                                                       
  height:950px ; 
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 

}
.carteModeRecto{

  text-align: -moz-center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  width: 370px; 
  text-align: left;
  margin:auto;
 text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.recto,.verso{
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    text-align: -ms-center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
   background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px black;
}

#photoprofil{
    background-image: url("img/photo_roger.jpg");
    width: 238px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
}

#photoprofil2{
    border: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
    width: 260px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px 150px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
}

.ligneinfo{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.buton,.buton2{
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #ca3439;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        margin:0  auto;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        border: 2px solid #cb353b;
}

.buton{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
}

.buton2{
  background-color: white;
  color: #2e4158;
  text-align: left;
  margin:0  auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
   width: 280px;
  height: 52px
}

.down{
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.partag{
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 43px;
}

.qrcode{
    border: 2px solid #cb353b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.buttontext2,.buttontext{
      color: #2e4158;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-size: 1em;
        
}

.buttontext{
        color: white;
}
    
.imgbutton,.imgbutton2{
        margin-left: 20px;
        height: 42px;
        width: 58px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 8px;
}
.imgbutton2{
  height: 42px;
  width: 43px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.info{
       
        margin-left: 35px;
}
   
.nom,.statu{
        font-size: 1.6em;
        color: #2e4158;
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center
}

.statu{
       margin-bottom: 30px;
       margin-top: 0px;
}

.texte{
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        color: #2e4158;
        font-size: 1.2em;
}
.carte{
  text-align: -moz-center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  width: 370px; 
  text-align: left;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso {

     -webkit-perspective: 740px;   
        perspective: 740px;
        margin-top: 50px;
     
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carte {

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carte .couche {
                      
        margin:0px !important;
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
        backface-visibility: hidden ;
                    
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carte .recto {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
                    
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carteModeRecto .recto {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(-0deg);
        transform: rotatey(-0deg);
                    
}
                    

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carteModeRecto .verso {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
        transform: rotatey(-180deg);
                    
}

.carte_visite_recto_verso .carteModeVerso .recto {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(+180deg);
        transform: rotatey(+180deg);
                    
}
                    
.carte_visite_recto_verso .carteModeVerso .verso {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg);
        transform: rotatey(0deg);
                    
}
      

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e4158;

}

.iconinfo{
          height: 29px;
          width: 25px;
}

.logo{
    width: 370px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}

.reseaux{

  text-align: left;
  margin:0  auto;
  margin-left:35px; 
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
} 

.qrcode{

  text-align: left;
  margin:0  auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 330px;
}

.imgqr{
  text-align: left;
  margin:0  auto;
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.imglogo{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta property="og:image" content="img/photo_roger.jpg">
    <meta name="image" content="img/photo_roger.jpg">
    <meta name="description" content="Location d'imprimantes et photocopieurs,
    Location et vente de matériel informatique,Téléphonie Voip et débit internet,Solutions de commutation" />
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    
    <title>Roger Duarte : Directeur Commercial - Axium Solutions </title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo2.jpg" type="image/jpg"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo2.jpg" type="image/jpg"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    

<div class="carte_visite_recto_verso" >
    <div class="carte carteModeRecto" >
        <div class="couche recto" >                      <!--DEBUT DU MODE RECTO-->
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="" class="imglogo"  >
            </div>

            <div>                                                                           <!--PHOTO DU CLIENT-->
                <div id="photoprofil2">
                    <div id="photoprofil"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nom" >  
                Roger Duarte
            </div>
            <div class="statu" >
                Directeur Commercial
            </div>
                <a href="download/vcard_roger.vcf"  download>
                    <div class="buton2">
               
                        <img src="img/ico_download.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton">
                        <div class="buttontext2" > Télécharger le contact</div>
                    </div></a>

                        <div class="buton" 
                        onclick="$(document).find('.carte').toggleClass('carteModeVerso');
                        $(document).find('.carte').toggleClass('carteModeRecto');">

                            <img src="img/ico_partage.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton2" >
                                <div class="buttontext"  >Partager</div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_mobile.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                                    <a href="tel:+33184008621"><div class="texte">01 84 00 86 21</div></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_phone.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                                    <a href="tel:+33662682503"><div class="texte">06 62 68 25 03</div></a>                  <!--ZONE INFORMATION-->
                            </div>

                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_sms.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                                    <a href="sms:+33662682503"><div class="texte">SMS</div></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_mail.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                                    <a href="mailto:Roger.duarte@axiumsolutions.fr"><div class="texte" >Roger.duarte@axiumsolutions.fr</div></a>
                            </div>
           
                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_web.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                                    <a href="http://www.axiumsolutions.fr"><div class="texte">www.axiumsolutions.fr</div></a>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="ligneinfo" >
                                <img src="img/ico_adresse.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo" >
                                    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/HdY48H9MVqRsX3KR9"><div class="texte" style="text-align: left;" >Immeuble Point Cardinal <br>
                                                                                                                            31 Avenue Pierre Brossolette <br>
                                                                                                                                91380 CHILLY MAZARIN</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="reseaux" >
                <div class="ligneinfo" >
                    <img src="img/ico_linkedin.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                        <a href=""><div class="texte">Linkedin</div></a>
                </div>

                <div class="ligneinfo" >                                                                  <!--ZONE RESEAUX SOCIAUX-->
                    <img src="img/ico_fb.jpg" alt="" class="iconinfo">
                        <a href=""><div class="texte">Facebook</div></a>
                </div>
        </div>                                                                                            <!--FIN MODE RECTO-->
    </div>       
    
   
                 <div class="couche verso" >                                                           <!--DEBUT MODE VERSO-->

                    <div class="logo" >
                        <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="" class="imglogo"  >
                    </div>

                        <a href="vcard_roger.vcf"  download>
                        <div class="buton2" >
                            <img src="img/ico_download.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton" >
                                <div class="buttontext2" >Télécharger le contact</div>
                        </div></a>

                        <div class="buton2">
                            <img src="img/ico_mail2.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton">
                                <div class="buttontext2"   >Partager Par Mail</div>                     <!--ZONE DE PARTAGE-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="buton2" >
                            <img src="img/ico_whatsapp.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton" >
                                <div class="buttontext2">Partager par Whatsapp</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="buton2" >
                            <img src="img/ico_copier.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton">
                                <div class="buttontext2"  >Copier le lien</div>
                        </div>

                        <div  class="buton" 
                        onclick="$(document).find('.carte').toggleClass('carteModeVerso');
                        $(document).find('.carte').toggleClass('carteModeRecto');">
                            <img src="img/ico_retour.jpg" alt="" class="imgbutton2">
                                    <div class="buttontext" >Retour</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="qrcode" >
                            <img src="img/qr_code.jpg" alt="" class="imgqr" >
                        </div>                                                                                                               <!--FIN DU MODE VERSO-->
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I change the title sorry !

Comment: Hi Joban, can you provide a screenshot of both versions of the website? And where have you placed the files? Are they in the same folders?

Comment: Hi Milkmannetje, below I post the mobile safari version that works well and the firofox and chrome version that doesn't work. For index.html and style.css files they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to use max-width instead of width. Max-width help to change size based on device size.

Example:

```
.verso{
  width:100%;
  max-width: 370px;                                                       
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, unfortunately its not changing anything. I can post an image of itself that its gives on my mobile with firefox and chrome.

[Mobile version on firefox and chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txnC7.png)

[Mobile version on safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO6yW.png)

Answer (score 0):

i spend sometimes for searching about this and i found something , i hope it helpful :
checkout the link : https://dev.to/neshaz/how-to-make-all-browsers-understand-your-css-2a4e